# Comparing two means (randomized experiment)

Tags: variance, t-test, experiment-design, normality-assumption

I'm kind of new to science :) for my thesis I worked on some study on health related behavior. There was an intervention for the experimental group and none for the control. So that seems to be a nice application for a basic independent two sample t-test! (or so I thought..) So I was checking my data and going through all the basic assumptions.

1. Normality: I can do Shapiro or Kolmogorov. But they say its non-normal distribution. Ah ok, I found the information that my samples (each about 500) may be too big (ref: [Normality in Large Samples](http://www.isixsigma.com/topic/test-of-normality-for-large-sample-size/)). So I only have QQplot and my gut feeling to find out about normality? :/
2. Next: Checking the homogeneity of variance of the samples. Ok, I go for two different forms of test (one Levene). But hugh, maybe Brown-Forsythe test is recommended when normality may be suspect (Wikipedia).

I am confident that my work isn't that wrong. Standard textbooks say, checking assumptions is soo important. Now, all assumptions are not met. So, what should I do next? Using transformations (z?) and first force my data meeting the assumptions? (I also have slightly different sample sizes because of attrition rate.)

Maybe you can give me some advice for my data. I think it is a really basic intervention experimental design and there must be common cases how to deal with those problems.

Thank you so much

**Update**

Oneway t-test is an easy way to determine each samples confidence intervals. For Control 95% is 3.102183 to 3.560402 and for Experimental it's 3.110003 3.561506. SE are 0.116629 respective 0.114918.

Now those values are 'looking good' to me. But what's my precise conclusion? Because each sample mean is within their 95% confidence interval it's representative for the population, right? What can I conclude from my relatively 'small' SE?

Regards

Comment: Hi Mac, sorry for the late response. Yes, your first conclusion is correct. Something you can do now is to increase your expected confidence and see how the upper and lower bound reacts to it. If you are at 99% and the bounds for both means still don't intersect then the certainty that one mean will always be larger than the other, increases. It also increases the confidence on how far they are apart and so on. Your small SE is an indicator for a slim distribution, which also is a reason why the tests behave so well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, whenever dealing with means, it is a good idea to check the standard error of both and see if their confidence intervals overlap. This gives you an intuition to start with. In fact you could build another statistical test on this that figures out your problem.

Why exactly are you shying away from the two sample t-test? Both, checking for equality, i.e., ${\mu _X} = {\mu _Y}$ or their difference, e.g. ${\mu _X} - {\mu _Y} < \omega$ where $\omega$ is your self-defined limit, should work fine. The later would be a one sample t-test. With a sample size of 500, you can assume your data is actually normally distributed given these tests. Especially for the differences of two means (${\mu _X} - {\mu _Y}$) this is easy to grasp (Central Limit Theorem).

Best

Comment: Ok, I stick to the two sample t-test. But for standard error and confidence intervals, didn't I have to know the true variance of the population. There's a difference between sample means and sample variance and population, right? Or put it in other words: How do I calculate those confidence intervals? :)

Comment: Update: Now I am aware of standard errors, confidence intervals and their calculation with R (I think)

Comment: I think you figured that out. You can estimate the variance from your sample. Don't forget: these tests always assume a lot of things (normal distributed data to name one. The data won't be perfectly normal distributed. Same goes for estimating mean and SE from the sample in the t-test. The conclusion is that we have a mathematical correct test but we should not fully trust it.